# How to send compressed API json response from AWS API gateway

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am working on social network application and my work is to write REST API's of application and provide data to application. I write my code and deployed my code on amazon server. For access I am using AWS API gateway to access REST API end point/web service. Now I want to send my json response in a compressed file for this purpose I research on gzip and someother zipped methods. Now I want to confirm that how I can implement gzip on amazon api gateway and is it correct to implement gzip on gateway or gateway itself managed it because application developers using amazone models for data parsing.

Answer (score 0):

To enable compression on an API, set the **minimumCompressionsSize** property to a non-negative integer between **0** and **10485760 (10M bytes)** when you create the API or after you've created the API.

You can enable or disable compression for an API by using the API Gateway console, the AWS CLI, or the API Gateway REST API.

For more details refer AWS documentation on [Enable Payload Compression for an API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-gzip-compression-decompression.html).